# To serialize the object into JSON

Tags: c#, json, highcharts

Below is my code for object

```
var obj_series = new
            {
                name = s_Name,
                data = p_Value

            };
```

which after serializing gives the below JSON format,

```
["series":[{"name":"01. Target"}],"data":[14,18,12]}]
```

How I am going to take multiple series name inside the object so that output can be as follows,

```
       "series":
        {
            name: 'Target',
            data: [14,18,12]
        }, {
            name: 'Alarm',
            data: [14,18,12]
        }, {
            name: 'Actual',
            data: [14,18,12]
        }

     List<object> modified_listofstrings = new List<object>();
     System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
     List<string> s_Name = new List<string>();
     List<float> p_Value = new List<float>();
     modified_listofstrings.Add(obj_series);
     jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

**Create classes for your objects:**

```
public class Serie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<long> Data { get; set; }

    public Serie()
    {
        Data = new List<long>();
    }
}

public class SeriesCollection
{
    public List<Serie> Series { get; set; }
    public SeriesCollection()
    {
        Series = new List<Serie>();
    }
}
```

**Serialize it:**

```
SeriesCollection collection = new SeriesCollection();

collection.Series.Add(new Serie() { Name = "Target", Data = { 1, 2, 3 } });
collection.Series.Add(new Serie() { Name = "Alarm", Data = { 1, 2, 3 } });
collection.Series.Add(new Serie() { Name = "Actual", Data = { 1, 2, 3 } });

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string seriesStr = jSearializer.Serialize(collection);

Output:
{"Series":[{"Name":"Target","Data":[1,2,3]},
           {"Name":"Alarm","Data":[1,2,3]},
           {"Name":"Actual","Data":[1,2,3]}
          ]}
```

**UPDATE:**

I don't know if it suits your needs, but here is another way:

```
var seriesdasda = new { series = new List<object>() };
seriesdasda.series.Add(new { name = "Target", data = { 1, 2, 3 }});
seriesdasda.series.Add(new { name = "Alarm", data = { 1, 2, 3 }});
seriesdasda.series.Add(new { name = "Actual", data = { 1, 2, 3 }});

string seriesStr2 = jSearializer.Serialize(seriesdasda);
```

Comment: Actually I am getting data from another web service which I have xml parsed in order to get the data in required format which I have again serialized to get JSON format, is there no solution of passing the values in object as shown above since I am using 4 different object and serializing it together...var obj4 = new { legend = new[] { obj_legend }, chart, series, xAxis };
                modified_listofstrings.Add(obj4);...and in this, series i want to take multiple values..

Comment: And also I am passing that series in same object that is obj4 coz I want that series to be sibling of chart,obj_legend and xAxis, I dont want to give it as another object, otherwise it create problem for me to plot the graph in highcharts.

Comment: Nopes..actually my s_Name and p_Value are list which contains three values each, when I write as said by you, I am getting 3 values each time,what I want is values from s_Name should get individually so that I get data against it and I cannot add fixed no s_Name and p_value, I do get the count from code itself.

Comment: You could loop through the list you have, on each iteration you create a single new object and add it to the series list. What is the relation between the two lists you have? The first index on the name list is related to the first index on the data list?

Comment: Can you please follow this link and tell me how should I do looping in list which I am using in var [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072130/to-loop-through-list-and-serialize-its-individual-data-into-json]

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correct, then there is no special consideration is required in order to serialize a custom collection using `JavaScriptSerializer`. Try [this](http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/csharp-net-development/csharp-serialize-object-to-json-format-using-javascriptserialization) approach.